# Angular2 Router doesn't work properly if parameter value contains dot (point)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to create nice URLs like: `http://localhost/data/2016.05/mike`
Here I'm trying to pass 3 parameters in URL: `["2016.05", "mike"]`.
I've created corresponding router config:

```
{ path: '/data/:date/:userName', component: DataDetails, name: 'DataDetails' }
```

This router allows me to access this URL from my program by calling something like:

```
this._router.navigateByUrl('/data/' + $data.year + '.' + data.month + '/' + data.userName );
```

After that I'm able to retrieve my parameters inside `DataDetails` component.

The problem occurs as soon as I try to access this link directly from browser (without accessing Home page first). Just by going to URL: `http://localhost/data/2016.05/mike`.
I'm receiving an error:

```
Cannot GET /data/2016.05/mike
```

As soon as I remove dot `.` from `2016.05` it works fine.

Is there any issue why I can't use `.` as a router parameter value?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a specific reason to not allow a `.` but I guess it just wan't added to the list of allowed characters.

`/` and `=` were added recently https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7312 to be allowed as part of parameter values instead of acting as delimiters.

Might be worth creating a bug report.

Comment: Thank you. I've opened corresponding issue for Angular 2: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8249. Let's see for the oficial response.

Answer (score 1):

dot is not allowed because it is used when you want to serve up a file such as yourserver:8080/mypic.png

Answer (score 1):

are you using webpack. in webpack we can make it working using making a small change in the webpack dev server config file.

```
historyApiFallback: {
      disableDotRule: true
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

***without override, just use URLSearchParams

```
let body = new URLSearchParams();
body.set('username', username);
body.set('password', password);
```

- from **angular DOC**

This class accepts an optional second parameter of ${@link QueryEncoder},
which is used to serialize parameters before making a request. By default,
`QueryEncoder` encodes keys and values of parameters using `encodeURIComponent`,
and then un-encodes certain characters that are allowed to be part of the query
according to IETF RFC 3986: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.

These are the characters that are not encoded: `! $ \' ( ) * + , ; A 9 - . _ ~ ? /`
*

- If the set of allowed query characters is not acceptable for a particular backend,
- `QueryEncoder` can be subclassed and provided as the 2nd argument to URLSearchParams.

override URLSearchParams to use your own method to encode characters not in the above list.

//**********

```
import {URLSearchParams, QueryEncoder} from '@angular/http';
class MyQueryEncoder extends QueryEncoder {
  encodeKey(k: string): string {
    return myEncodingFunction(k);
  }

  encodeValue(v: string): string {
    return myEncodingFunction(v);
  }
}

let params = new URLSearchParams('', new MyQueryEncoder());
```